# install system depencies of a ros hydro installation

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-hydro, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

maybe someone can help me with my little problem regarding ROS.

Let's say we have a valid ros hydro installation from source in a none root / system directory (for e.g. installed to a mounted /home partition).
Now i want to use a freshly installed system (means root / partition) without any ros system depencies installed. The guide for installing ros from source only mentions how to install the depencies with rosdep which uses the list of packages in the src directory.

How can i resolve / install all the system-depencies the ros-installation have?

With best regards,

Torsten

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175146/install-system-depencies-of-a-ros-hydro-installation/) by [Auron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19014/auron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to do this in the same way you would from the folder with sources, i.e.

```
rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/hydro/install -i --rosdistro hydro
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0